# Sp_BlitzIndex - A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server

Tags: sql-server, sp-blitzindex

I am running  v8.13 - February 15, 2023 of the Brent Ozar sp_BlitzIndex function against  SQL Server 2017 Web Edition.
Whenever I run on a specific database as below , I get the "A transport-level...." type error after about a minute.

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_BlitzIndex @DatabaseName='XXXX', @SchemaName='dbo', @TableName='yyyyy';
```

If I run the same with a different DatabaseName, but the same table, it runs OK. We have several customers all with the same database structure.
The message tab is as below :

```
Inserting data into #IndexColumns for clustered indexes and heaps
Inserting data into #IndexColumns for nonclustered indexes
Inserting data into #IndexSanity
Checking partition count
Preferring non-2012 syntax with LEFT JOIN to sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats
Inserting data into #IndexPartitionSanity
Inserting data into #MissingIndexes
Inserting data into #ForeignKeys
Inserting data into #ForeignKeys
Gathering Computed Column Info.
Gathering Trace Flag Information
Gathering Temporal Table Info
Updating #IndexSanity.key_column_names
Updating #IndexSanity.partition_key_column_name
Updating #IndexSanity.key_column_names_with_sort_order
Updating #IndexSanity.key_column_names_with_sort_order_no_types (for create tsql)
Updating #IndexSanity.include_column_names
Updating #IndexSanity.include_column_names_no_types (for create tsql)
Updating #IndexSanity.count_key_columns and count_include_columns
Updating index_sanity_id on #IndexPartitionSanity
Inserting data into #IndexSanitySize
Determining index usefulness
Updating #IndexSanity.referenced_by_foreign_key
Update index_secret on #IndexSanity for NC indexes.
Update index_secret on #IndexSanity for heaps and non-unique clustered.
Populate #IndexCreateTsql.
Populate #PartitionCompressionInfo.
Update #PartitionCompressionInfo.
Update #IndexSanity for filtered indexes with columns not in the index definition.
@TableName specified, giving detail only on that table.
Msg 121, Level 20, State 0, Line 1
A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.)
```

Any ideas on what I can try and check/change to get it to complete ?

Comment: Does the database pass DBCC CHECKDB with extended logical checks turned on? I've seen issues like this when the database is corrupt.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response @BrentOzar. Yes, it passes all checks. I did find that it was at a lower compatibility level than all the others, and after some testing we moved it up to 120 and then ran Sp_BlitzIndex again. Same result, but there was some more info in the error log "Unknown,SQL Server Assertion: File: <sql\ntdbms\include\typesystem\_retypesbase.inl><c/> line=338 Failed Assertion = 'PbValGetConst()[CSsVariant::OFF_VER] == CSsVariant::CURR_VER'. This error may be timing-related"   I will see if it's all good after the server has been re-booted